# I cannot figure out how to refer to a variable outside a loop(C++)

Tags: c++

Basically my problem is that I created a variable(string) outside a loop, and I want to use it inside the loop. Here is an example code to try to explain better:

```
int myage = 0; // set by user
int currentyear = 2015;

cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
cin >> myage;

for(int i=0; i>98; i++) {
  myage=myage+1;
  currentyear=currentyear+1;

  cout << "In " << currentyear << " you will be " << myage << " years old." << endl;
}
```

This is just a quick example I made up to try to explain it better, so my question is: is there any way I could use `myage` or `currentyear` variables in this loop? If yes, how?

Do not hesitate to ask if you need more info or specific data.

Comment: If you couldn't use them, you'd get a compiler error.

Comment: I can't use myage inside the loop(you are correct)

Comment: You have changed your question, and now your code works as described when compiled and run. Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: Yes, it says the variable myage might not be initialized

Comment: Your example code doesn't reproduce the error for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code I pasted in wasn't exactly the same for me, so it created an error. It now works, thanks to Arun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop never executes

```
for(int i=0; i>98; i++){
```

since `i>98` is `false`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, but I wrote this quickly as an example to try to explain my problem better.

Comment: Frustratingly, the OP changed the question which makes this answer obsolete.

Comment: Was I not supposed to change it?

Comment: Yes, it is frustrating indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, absolutely. A for loop is almost more of a convenience syntax, giving you a place to specify an initial condition, a break condition, and a command to execute every iteration. To the best of my knowledge you can use as many or as few of these as you want, for example

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int myage = 0;
    for(; myage<10; myage++)
        std::cout << myage << std::endl;
}
```

will print out the numbers 0 through 9.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is already answered, you could improve and shorten your code by using += operator like this:
 `myage += 1;`

or this:
`myage++;`

instead of `myage=myage+1;`

Answer (score 0):

Understanding scope is important. Loops and functions create a scope, and they can always access things at a higher up scope; however, things cannot be accessed from a smaller scope. Objects exist for the entire duration of their scope, and anything within that scope can access them.

```
// Global scope:
int g = 0; // everything in this file can access this variable

class SomeClass
{
    // Class scope
    int c = 0;
    void ClassFunction()
    {
        // ClassFunction scope
        // Here we can access anything at global scope as well as anything within this class's scope:
        int f = 0;

        std::cout << g << std::endl; // fine, can access global scope
        std::cout << c << std::endl; // fine, can access class scope
        std::cout << f << std::endl; // fine, can access local scope
    }
    // Outside of ClassFunction, we can no longer access the variable f
};

void NonClassFunction()
{
    // NonClassFunction scope
    // We can access the global scope, but not class scope
    std::cout << g << std::endl;

    int n1 = 0;
    for (...)
    {
        // New scope
        // Here we can still access g and n1
        n1 = g;
        int x = 0;
    }
    // We can no longer access x, as the scope of x no longer exists

    if (...)
    {
        // New scope
        int x = 0; // fine, x has not been declared at this scope
        {
            // New scope
            x = 1;
            g = 1;
            n1 = 1;
            int n2 = 0;
        }
        // n2 no longer exists
        int n2 = 3; // fine, we are creating a new variable called n2
    }
}
```

Hopefully this has helped explain scope to you. With all this new information in mind, the answer is yes: you can access your variables within a for loop because the scope of those variables persists within an inner scope.

Comment: Very helpful, as I am learning code. Thank you for sharing this!